# How to access an attribute of an object defined inside another class in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I have these three classes

```
import datetime

class MetalType(object):
    Silver, Gold, Platinum = range(0, 3)

class Metals(object):
    def __init__(self,pType,pVariant):
        self.type= pType
        self.variant=pVariant

class Transaction(object):
    id=0
    def __init__(self,pMetal,pQuantity,pTransType,pPrice):
        Transaction.id+=1
        self.transdate= datetime.date.today()
        self.metal= pMetal
        self.quantity =pQuantity
        self.TransType =pTransType
        self.price =pPrice
```

Now I want to create an Transaction object and print the type

```
Silver=Metals(MetalType.Silver,"Heraus")
Transaction1=Transaction(Metals,100,"buy",100.00)
print(Transaction1.metal.type)
```

But I get the following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'Metals' has no attribute 'type'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `pMetal` is a *class*, not an *instance*. Did you mean `Transaction(Silver, 100, "buy", 100.00)`?

Comment: Yes! I am an Idiot.Thank you

Comment: Also you should read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and I don't think the `id` is doing what you'd like it to.

Comment: The id is to keep track of the number of transactions happened. I created two Transaction objects. when I 'print(Transaction.id)'. It gives me 2. I am making it as a class variable. I am not assigning id to individual transactions. I gave a very misleading  name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Transaction1=Transaction(Metals,100,"buy",100.00)
```

should become

```
Transaction1=Transaction(Silver,100,"buy",100.00)
```

Also, a friendly advice: don't use capitalized variable names as to not confuse them with class names. Your choice of capitalization made this harder to spot than it should have been.